Module not found Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported
Im trying to restructure my source code to monorepo, after the refactor had been done, i run the command "yarn start" and this error comeup
Failed to compile.
./src/constants/routes.ts
Module not found: You attempted to import packages/appliciant/page/AppliciantDetail which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
This is my project structure:
My routes.ts look like this:
import SignInPage from '../pages/SignIn';
import AppliciantDetail from 'packages/appliciant/page/AppliciantDetail';
import AppliciantListPage from 'packages/appliciant/page/AppliciantListPage';
import UserRolesListPage from 'packages/userRoles/page/UserRolesListPage';
import UserRoleDetail from 'packages/userRoles/page/UserRolesDetail';
import RecruitmentListPage from 'packages/recruitment/page/RecruitmentListPage';
import RecruitmentCreate from 'packages/recruitment/page/RecruitmentCreate';
import PermissionGroupListPage from 'packages/permissionGroup/page/PermissionGroupListPage';
import PermissionGroupDetail from 'packages/permissionGroup/page/PermissionGroupDetail';
import EvaluationListPage from 'packages/evaluation/page/EvaluationListPage';
import EvaluationFormDetail from 'packages/evaluation/page/EvaluationFormDetail';
import EvaluationAct from 'packages/evaluation/page/EvaluationAct';
import PageError from '../pages/PageError';

const routes = [
  { path: '/sign-in', element: SignInPage, isPublic: true },

  { path: '/', element: RecruitmentListPage },
  { path: '/recruit/:id', element: RecruitmentCreate },
  { path: '/recruit/create', element: RecruitmentCreate },

  { path: '/appliciant', element: AppliciantListPage },
  { path: '/appliciant/:id', element: AppliciantDetail },

  { path: '/user-roles', element: UserRolesListPage },
  { path: '/user-roles/:id', element: UserRoleDetail },

  { path: '/permission-group', element: PermissionGroupListPage },
  { path: '/permission-group/:id', element: PermissionGroupDetail },
  { path: '/permission-group/create', element: PermissionGroupDetail },

  { path: '/evaluation', element: EvaluationListPage },
  { path: '/evaluation/:id', element: EvaluationFormDetail },
  { path: '/evaluation/create', element: EvaluationFormDetail },

  { path: `/applicant/feedback`, element: EvaluationAct },

  { path: '/pageError', element: PageError },
];

export default routes;



Did you do any special treatment in project setup for "packages" dir? You're supposed to either install/link monorepo packages to node_modules so they could be imported as any other dependencies. Or alias them, especially if they are not built
